# ¿Cómo abrir un archivo swf en un formulario de windows pero sin una ruta de acceso en el disco duro?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Quería saber si existe la posibilidad de abrir un juego flash dentro de un formulario de windows sin colocar su ruta de acceso como por ejemplo `C:\user\IRAIDA\desktop\papasburgeria.swf`, quiero saber si hay otra manera de abrirlo sin necesidad de predefinir su ruta

Este es el juego que quiero abrir.

[image: juego]

Pero para abrirlo me tengo que ir a la propiedad Movie y colocar la ruta así.
**¿hay alguna manera de evitar esto?**

[image: ruta de acceso]

**Algo así como colocarlo en mi carpeta de recursos y luego llamarlo.**

Comment: podrías ponerlo como recurso incrustado en tu proyecto y leerlo desde ahí dentro de tu dll, (en inglés es embedded resource)

Comment: hola muy buena idea @jtaborga, pero como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y comparte lo que has realizado, la parte de tu código donde abres el archivo swf. para que te pueda ayudar

Comment: listo @jtaborga ya edite la pregunta y añadi mas informacion

Comment: @Eliezer te deje esta respuesta para que pruebes si cumple con tus necesidades: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383769/46896

Answer (score 0):

## Hay varias maneras de hacerlo:

### Si tienes una URL puedes implementar esta soluciona: [Documentación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1735477/4717133)

> **[Traduccion]** ¿Esa ruta es siempre una ruta de archivo? ¿O puede ser una URL? Debería ser bastante simple configurar un servidor web temporal localhost usando `HttpListener` (o similar), que transmita el archivo en respuesta a una solicitud http.
> Otra posibilidad serían las tuberías con nombre; Me pregunto si puede convencer al control de que abra una tubería con nombre como si fuera un archivo. (tienen una ruta de archivo lógica, después de todo). Sin embargo, apenas los he tocado, así que no puedo decir al 100% si funcionaría.

### También puedes hacer uso de Embedded Resource: [Documentación](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1de60b6b-fc8b-48a5-b41f-1a3d25756700/embedded-flash-object-in-my-c-app?forum=csharpgeneral)

> **[Traduccion]** `ResourceManager.GetObject` no funciona si acaba de configurar la acción de compilación en "Recurso incrustado". Necesitas usar una secuencia:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream file = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.Filename");
byte[] data = new byte[file.Length];
file.Read(data, 0, bytes.Length);
```

> **[Traduccion]** En lugar de configurar la acción de compilación, puede abrir `Propiedades/Recursos.resx` y agregar el archivo. Luego puede acceder directamente al recurso con:

```
byte[] data = Properties.Resources.Filename;
```

**En fin Puedes adaptarlo a tus necesidades**